# Object property name as function argument with ensured type in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, object-properties, type-definition

How to write definition of type in function argument which is one of object properties with same type?

For example I have object:

```
type Article = {
  name: string;
  quantity: number;
  priceNet: number;
  priceGross: number;
};
```

and want to write function which summarise price depending on price type property:

```
function summarise(article: Article, priceTypeProperty: NeededProperty) {
  return article[priceTypeProperty] * article.quantity;
}
```

How definition of `NeededProperty` should look like to ensure typescript that it's one of Article properties `priceNet` or `priceGross` and it is `number` type?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAggTsAlgYwDbQLxQN4CgpQB2AhgLYQBcUAzsHIoQOYDc+UAjgK7GFKhWFOpAEYQ4rAmHrIIAOQjABQ0eLZSUEAOJwA9tWpKRY1gF9WuUJCgAFaRFs7ICRBGpQsAawggdAMxxsANoA0lAMUF4+-vBIaNDEbqEQAB7AEIQAJm4ABuoyACTYtPRMJtlsBAD8sM5xIQC6UClpmW6CRnAVBFDVwV0EAhAAbmJdgyNw9VQxKOgNpubIOoS0HNy8iKDuUACM5r6chMhIyzRCpMT01BAAFJex6NO16AA0UHkQACrg9rpO-DY7A5-i5qABKAIEOAKThwQhQe6zCCBD7fSDAsSgRoAKjWPD4IFMuCAA) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes, it works but it's very complicated :/ See my answer which is much simpler: [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76882361/7008104)

Comment: Just spell out `priceTypeProperty: 'priceNet' | 'priceGross'`, am I missing something?

Comment: @Bergi your solution doesn't give typescript information about type of `'priceNet' | 'priceGross'` and also not ensures that Article object contains that properties.

Comment: @PiotrWitkoś Not sure what you mean by "*doesn't give typescript information*"? And it certainly would complain about the expression `article[priceTypeProperty]` if `priceTypeProperty` was not a property of `Article`, or if that property was not numeric.

Comment: @Bergi I mean that `priceTypeProperty: 'priceNet' | 'priceGross'` specifies only that `priceTypeProperty` can be string with value `'priceNet'` or `'priceGross'`, but it doesn't keep information what type will have `article[priceTypeProperty]`. My [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76882361/7008104) ensures typescript that `article[priceTypeProperty]` is `number` so it not shows error

Comment: @PiotrWitkoś No. `article[priceTypeProperty]` is properly inferred to type `number`, regardless how you do it. Using `… & keyof Article` (or the same thing with `Pick`) does not guarantee that the properties are numbers either, it would not compile if you were to change the `Article` property types - just the same as the simple solution. However, if you were the `Article` property *names*, your solution would continue to compile (but complain only at the call sites) while mine would complain at the property access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previous answer by Yaman Abd is correct, but I found little more pretty solution:

### Solution

```
type NeededType = keyof Pick<Article, 'priceNet' | 'priceGross'>;
```

### Explanation

- `keyof` makes string type from one of given object properties
- `Pick` is utility type that helps to select properties from Article type. So we are ensured that property is included in Article object type.

This solution suggest properties which you can use while defining type `NeededType`.

### Example

So proper example look like this:

```js
type Article = {
  name: string;
  quantity: number;
  priceNet: number;
  priceGross: number;
};
    
type NeededType = keyof Pick<Article, 'priceNet' | 'priceGross'>;

function summarise(article: Article, priceTypeProperty: NeededType) {
  return article[priceTypeProperty] * article.quantity;
}
    
// Usage
const myArticle: Article = {
  name: "Example Article",
  quantity: 5,
  priceNet: 10,
  priceGross: 12
};
    
const totalPriceNet = summarise(myArticle, "priceNet"); // Works
const totalPriceGross = summarise(myArticle, "priceGross"); // Also works
    
const totalPriceGross = summarise(myArticle, "otherPrice"); // does not work
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this you could use `keyof` and a type constraint to make sure that the parameter is one of the valid key names in the `Article` type and must be (`priceNet` or `priceGross`) and its a `number` type

```
type Article = {
  name: string;
  quantity: number;
  priceNet: number;
  priceGross: number;
};

function summarise(article: Article, priceTypeProperty: keyof Article & ("priceNet" | "priceGross")) {
  return article[priceTypeProperty] * article.quantity;
}

// Usage
const myArticle: Article = {
  name: "Example Article",
  quantity: 5,
  priceNet: 10,
  priceGross: 12
};

const totalPriceNet = summarise(myArticle, "priceNet"); // Works
const totalPriceGross = summarise(myArticle, "priceGross"); // Also works

const totalPriceGross = summarise(myArticle, "otherPrice"); // does not work
```